# I need to run standalone-chrome-debug in offline mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-docker

I have a linux server, with no connectivity to github (it's blocked in our office), and need to run standalone-chrome-debug docker image.
So in my side, i clone the repo and transfer it to the linux machine, but when i run the docker command:
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 0:5900 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1 selenium/standalone-chrome-debug

i got a lot of error, such as entry_point.sh not found, and different similar issues of missing files, so my question is:

how can i make this docker run successfully , if i have the repository locally, and have no access to github, can you assist me with this issue ?

Comment: Add more details to your question. What are the original steps and what are the steps that you take considering you have no access to github.

Comment: Hi Alexy, the command i am trying to run is:

Comment: docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 0:5900 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1 selenium/standalone-chrome-debug. 

And there is no chance to get access to github, it's blocked

Comment: I am not sure why do you need to clone the repo. Images are taken from docker registry. This is why I'm asking to provide the steps (or tutorial) that you would be following if you would have your github accessible..